# Lossless compression of an ordered series of 29 digits (each 0 to 5 Likert scale)

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a survey with 29 questions, each with a 5-point Likert scale (0=None of the time; 4=Most of the time). I'd like to compress the total set of responses to a small number of alpha or alphanumeric characters, adding a check digit to the end.

So, the set of responses `00101244231023110242231421211` would get turned into something like `A2CR7HW4`. This output would be part of a printout that a non-techie user would enter on a website as a shortcut to entering the entire string. I'd want to avoid ambiguous characters, such as `0,O,D,I,l,5,S`, leaving me with 21 or 22 characters to use (uppercase only). Alternatively, I could just stick with capital alpha only and use all 26 characters.

I'm thinking to convert each pair of digits to a letter (5^2=25, so the whole alphabet is adequate). That would reduce the sequence to 15 characters, which is still longish to type without errors.

Any other suggestions on how to minimize the length of the output?

EDIT: BTW, for context, the survey asks 29 questions about mental health symptoms, generating a predictive risk for 4 psychiatric conditions. Need a code representing all responses.

Comment: What is the goal, what are you trying to achieve in a broader context? Relational data base queries might get awkward with custom encoding/compression, and a contemporary DB engine might offer compression - while the price for solid state storage keeps spiralling down. 5² is less than the number of Roman characters, 5³ less than 2^7: ASCII without `'\0', '\r', '\n'` :-/

Comment: @greybeard: The goal is for the survey to -- in addition to providing its current report on mental health risk based on symptoms -- to provide a code which, when entered into _some other site or app_, possibly unrelated to my site, would be a convenient and simple interoperable way to transfer the responses given on my site to the other site/app (without having to answer the questions all over again). The other site/app would provide additional insights to the pattern of responses, after converting the code back into the original survey's responses. Google whatsmym3 if want to see.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of a sequence of 29, say, digits?

Comment: Disadvantage is the onerous nature of human entering these into a field on a website. The fewer the characters, the less error ... and improved usability. You want a 29-digit credit card number? Guess I could do a QR code, but that is less accessible to general public, but it's a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, choose a set of permissible characters, i.e.

```
characters = "ABC..."
```

Then, prefix the input-digits with a 1 and interpret it as a quinary number:

```
100101244231023110242231421211
```

Now, convert this quinary number to a number in base-"strlen(characters)", i.e. base26 if 26 characters are to be used:

```
02 23 18 12 10 24 04 19 00 15 14 20 00 03 17
```

Then, use these numbers as index in "characters", and you have your encoding:

```
CVSMKWETAPOUADR
```

For decoding, just reverse the steps.

Comment: You've fleshed out my initial thought in a usable way, so that is helpful. But can it be shortened any further? (I don't think it can.)

Comment: Not by using just an encoding I think. And there is probably too less data to utilize a real _compression_ algorithm. If the numbers tend to repeat often a runlength-encoding could do some good, but this doesn't seem to be the case either.

Comment: I looked at RLE, but not long enough runs to make that feasible.

Comment: @HITshrink The disadvantage of this scheme is that it's possible to corrupt many answers by corrupting a single letter. I know you're planning to have a check digit, but...

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Of course, the more information you convey in one character, the more information is corrupted if that character gets corrupted. I.e. with an alphabet of 26 characters you can transport ~4.7 bits per char, for one answer you need ~2.322 bits. So 2-3 answers can be impacted with an incorrect typed char. More corruption occurs when inserting/leaving out a char, but that's the same with most methods (even when using plaintext 0-4).

Comment: @Ctx With your encoding in a non-25 base, it's possible to change every single answer by making a mistake in the high-order encoded character.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Indeed the corruption is fatal for the rest of the answers when the source- and target base are relatively prime. The bigger the LCM, the less is the impact. Hence it is advisable to choose a multiple of 5 for the target base to minimize the impact.

Comment: Thinking again, indeed a power of 5 is needed, but then 25 would be the only option. One has to see if this outweighs the benefit of having a compact representation.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of using base 25, so that each character represents exactly two responses. I would break this up into 4 groups of characters, including a check digit, to reduce user error. The benefit of using 15 vs 29 characters outweighs the risk of a single character error affecting two responses (in the former) versus affecting one response (in the latter).

Comment: The next step is constructing a check digit that maximizes the likelihood of catching an error of transposition or wrong character. I've never done anything with check digits. Any pointers as to a good guide in this situation? I think it involves position-level mod calculations, but this is getting over my head.

Comment: Rather than using one check position, split the code in three parts of 5 (alphabet size ≥ 23: use small Roman characters) or 4 positions (alphabet size ≥ 47: issues start with I ↔ l (`I <> l`)) and one check position with each group - checking all (proper) positions of the other groups. If two check codes indicate an error, it probably is in the group both check, if only one doesn't figure, that check-code probably is incorrect. _The 2nd group seems incorrect_ doesn't sound as disheartening with a group of 6(or 5) positions as _Incorrect input_ with ≥ 12 positions.

Answer (score 2):

If the five answers are all equally likely, then the best you can do is `ceiling(29 * log(5) / log(n))` symbols, where `n` is the number of symbols in your alphabet.  (The base of the logarithm doesn't matter, so long as they're both the same.)

So for your 22 symbols, the best you can do is 16. For 26 symbols, the best is 15, as you described for 25. If you use 49 characters (e.g. some subset of the upper and lower case characters and the digits), you can get down to 12. The best you'll be able to do with printable ASCII characters would be 11, using 70 of the 94 characters.

The only way to make it smaller would be if the responses are *not* all equally likely and are heavily skewed. Though if that's the case, then there's probably something wrong with the survey.

Comment: that last comment is insightful. The responses are skewed to the left in lower risk populations, and slightly to the right in higher risk pops. In a  web-based sampling (non-clinical population of self-referred people, so higher risk) of 24,000 assessments, here are the frequencies of responses with a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 -- 5.43 4.27 6.57 6.59 6.14.  //  I conclude that no further compression based on RLE or similar algorithm would help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in a specific language?

If you want to be really thrifty about it you might want to consider encoding the data at bit level.

Since there are only 5 possible answers per question you could do this with only 3 bits:

```
000
001
010
011
100
```

Your end result would be a string of bits, at 3-bits per answer so a total of 87 bits or 10 and a bit bytes.

EDIT - misread the question slightly, there are 5 possible answers not 4, my mistake.

The only problem now is that for 4 of your 5 answers you're wasting a bit...you ain't gonna benefit much from going to this much trouble I wouldn't say but it's worth considering.

EDIT:

I've been playing about with it and it's difficult to work out a mechanism that allows you to use both 2 and 3 bit values.

Since your output would be a 97 bit binary value you'd need ot be able make the distinction between 2 and 3 bits values when converting back to the original values.

If you're working with a larger number of values there are some methods you could use, like having a reserved bit for each values that can be used to sort of type a value and give it some meaning. But working with so few bits as it is, it's hard to shave anything off.

Your output at 97 bits could be padded out to 128 bits, which would give you 4 32-bit values if you wanted to simplify it. this 128 bit value would be like a unique fingerprint representing a specific set of answers. There are many ways you can represnt 128 bits.

But in the end borking at bit-level is about as good as it gets when it comes to actual compression and encoding of data...if you can express 5 unique values in less than 3 bits I'd be suitably impressed.

Comment: How do you represent a 5-value range in two bits?

Comment: Beg your pardon, you can't - you might be able to figure out a way to work with 2 and 3 bit values, it would take a bit of brow beating if at all possible but probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @Nunchy You cannot express 5 values in less than 3 bit, but you can express n 5 values in less than n*3 bit.

Comment: @Nunchy No specific language at this point. Prototyping it in Excel (!) as a start. Will eventually be in .net or maybe java. I thought of the wasted bits from 4/5ths of the possible answers, but not gonna mess with a mix of 2s and 3s.

Comment: True, there would be ways to make it smaller but you;d be unlikely to save much in the end and it probably wouldn't be worth the effort for all it is.

Not sure why the results of these surverys need to be input manually in such a format, but seems this is more about how to conveniently represent an entire set of answers in a way that it's convenient to read and input by a user. There are many ways it could be done.

Comment: @Nunchy: "seems this is more about how to conveniently represent an entire set of answers in a way that it's convenient to read and input by a user."  Exactly

Comment: The way to use 2 and 3-bit values would be a prefix code: 00, 01, 10, 110, 111. Each response averages 2.4 bits (assuming that they are equally likely).

Comment: But when strung together, how to know which are the pairs and which are the triplets?

Comment: A prefix system would be useful if there were more answers per question but here it qwould be redundant. Seems this question is about compression again - if the object is to produce an output that is easy to read, manage and maintain/input by a user as well as compress...I'd say a sacrifice will have to be made in one area or the other...for all it's worth saving an extra couple of bits.